# Nginx Domain Name Redirects with Maps

Tags: nginx

I have a long list of older domain names that need to be redirected to a path on a newer domain - ie. foo.com, bar.com should be redirected to foobar.com/one and foobar.com/two (ie. I can't regex the new URL out of the old one)

My attempt:

```
map $uri $newdomain {
    include redirects/domains.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name .......; # this handles all of the domains

    if ($newdomain) {
        return 301 $newdomain;
    }

    # the rest of the config - handling the correct new domain request
}

# in redirects/domains.conf
foo.com    foobar.com/one;
bar.com    foobar.com/two;
foo.com/bar    foobar.com/three;
```

Nginx reloads successfully, but it doesn't apply the redirects.

All of the examples of maps I've seen only have it handling paths - i.e. /page-one to /page-two

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add $host variable before $uri like this

```
map $host$uri $newdomain {
  include redirects/domains.conf;
}
```

Comment: ah - I see. I couldn't find out from the docs quite how the map syntax was supposed to work, but that makes it all much more clear! thanks.